# Global Actions Missing - Lightning

Tags: global-actions

For some reason Global Actions aren't appearing on the drop down menu for my lightning console. Completely blank.

[image: Empty]

I'm an admin of SFDC, so permissions to creating records is no issue.

I've checked to ensure that it is added to the Publisher Layout

I've tried creating a new button with a record type selected - Still no luck.

[image: Action button]

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATED:

[image: Publisher Layout]

Comment: Did you add the action to the publisher layout? If you did add check the publisher layout assignment and make sure the action is added to the layout of the user in context.Take a look at this trailhead : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/units/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_global

Comment: There is a walkthrough link in the trailhead link, follow the link and you should see the custom action under the + sign. You can add custom actions to global actions starting spring 17 https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LjJsAAK

Comment: Yup - followed that guide. And yes, it's added to the publisher layout. To be sure i even created a new layout to test - same problem.

Comment: Using Chrome - Everything else in lightning appears to be working as it should. And I compare to my developer edition, works fine with the same configuration. Just really strange...

Comment: Do you see the standard actions? what browser are you on, looking at the image in question, I see only create, do you see new account/note/case

Comment: Just updated the post with a new image of the Publisher Layout. As mentioned I also tried creating a new layout and assigning it to my profile - no luck

Comment: Do you see standard actions atleast? from your original image I see only create and nothing under it

Comment: Hrm, interesting - I just removed everything and left only a single action (which now appears). To answer your previous question, nothing was appearing under create, not even standard actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else reading this, not sure on the cause, but the fix was to remove all buttons from the Global Publisher Layout and add each item back one by one.