# Global action drop down not working in Lightning

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Somehow my drop-down for global action in lightning is not working. I have gone through the [trailhead link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/units/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_global) as well as some similar questions on stack [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163485/global-actions-missing-lightning) and [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DYKGQA4). But I think I stuck with some salesforce bug. Becasuse when I toggle the device toolbar in my chrome with mobile resolution. its showing those global action see the below picture.
[image: Mobile view global action] but when I open the same layout in desktop mode the global action button is not showing any drop down see the below.

> not even standard actions.

[image: Desktop Lightning mode]

I got my head into this issue from last 6-7 hours but I am not able to figure out what is the issue and how to resolve this.
FYI I have also check the permission for the global action those are also available. as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=adding_actions_using_ple.htm&type=5)
The same issue persists for the quick action also. I have check the record type assignment and permission. If anybody has any doubt about the record type assignment, I have access to these actions in Salesforce1 app on the same browser.

Comment: please refrain from asking for immediate or urgent asisistance, it is considered rude, and will not improve your chances of getting an answer. Thanks

Comment: thanks @glls, do u hv any solution for the above issue?